# postgres debezium connector and jdbc sink to postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, debezium-connect

I want to replicate data from a postgres database to another postgres database using connectors, but the table does not created in the second database, here is my config:

```
CREATE TABLE events(
    identity_id STRING PRIMARY KEY,
    name STRING,
    family_name STRING,
    event_type STRING
)
```

and this is connector and sink,

```
{"name": "postgres-source",
  "config": {"connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "database.hostname": "postgres",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.dbname" : "kafka_test",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "database.whitelist": "kafka_test",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.kafka_test",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope"
  }
}

{"name": "lead-sink",
"config": {"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max":"10",
  "topics": "events",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/kafka_test?user=postgres&password=postgres",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "auto.create": "true",
  "auto.evolve": "true",
  "insert.mode": "upsert",
  "pk.fields": "identity_id",
  "pk.mode": "record_key"
}
}
```

I try different approach from listening to topic by itself, and also using ksql
I want to produce same table into the second postgres database.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: no, I can't see any errors in terminal.
can you just check with me if this configs are correct??